# How to enable protocol without GUI in tshark?

Tags: wireshark, protocol

```
tshark -G heuristic-decodes | grep dvb
----output-----
udp     dvb-s2_modeadapt        F
```

how to turn it True with command line or config ?

OS:ubuntu 22.04

thx all.

Comment: According to this https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/AppToolstshark.html wouldn't it be `tshark --enable-heuristic dvb-s2_modeadapt`?

Comment: @Terrance That will not work, have you tried it yourself or you are just reading documentation?

Comment: Have you tried anything?  I seem to have had the wrong name.  I have never used this application before and I did some more searching about tshark and all I needed what the shortname for it.  It appears to capture as `sudo tshark --enable-heuristic dvb_s2_udp` by reading through things like https://ask.wireshark.org/question/13870/dissection-ethernetdvb-s2/

Comment: What @Terrance mentioned will start the capture but using `tshark -G heuristic-decodes | grep dvb` it will still be set to false.  Unfortunately, you cannot directly enable or disable heuristic decodes like this from the command line using tshark.

Comment: And yes, I have tried this.  I did install both Wireshark and tshark and I have no need for either, but for the sake of testing I have done this.  There is no way either through the Wireshark application or through the command line of tshark to set the `udp dvb-2_modeadapt F` to `T` even in the `~/.config/wireshark/preferences` file.  But the command I state above did start capturing without an issue.